# How to prove using elementary methods that this function is everywhere continuous but nowhere differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be the function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ by the formula
$$ f(x) \colon= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cos \left( 3^n x \right). $$

How to show (rigorously but through elementary logic) that the function $f$ is

(1) continuous everywhere?

(2) differentiable nowhere?

This example has been given in Sec. 6.1 in the book *Introduction To Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition. So ideally I would like to have an argument based purely on the machinary developed in the book upto this point.

However, a proof using the relevant results in the subsequent chapters and sections of the book would also be fine, provided that due references are given of all the facts used.

I do know that the infinite series in question does converge (in fact it converges absolutely). So the function is defined everywhere on the real line.

Comment: It converges *uniformly* by the Weierstrass M-test, which at once implies continuity. Item (2) is the more difficult part.

Comment: For the second question you can look at section 2 of [this paper](http://www.ohiouniversityfaculty.com/mohlenka/20132/4993-4994/20132McLaughlin_report.pdf) about the Weierstrass function.